# Passing table parameter using select clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 types:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE id_type AS OBJECT
   (
     id NUMBER(19, 0)
   );

   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE id_table AS TABLE OF id_type;
```

And I have a function A(param IN id_table).

Now, if I have another function using first one, how am I supposed to pass the param like that A(SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)? Can I only do it manually creating an id_table var, filling it and then passing to A() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_ids     id_table;
  l_return  <<data type>>;
BEGIN
  SELECT id_type( 1 )
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids
    FROM dual;
  l_return := a( l_ids );
END;
```

It's not obvious, though, why you have an `id_type` in this case.  It would seem more logical to simply declare `id_table`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE id_table
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER(19,0);
```

It's also not obvious whether you are really intending to populate the collection by selecting from dual.  If you really want to have a single-element collection, you can simply initialize it.  I'm guessing, however, that you really intend to populate the collection by querying a table other than `DUAL` in which case you'd prefer the `BULK COLLECT`

```
DECLARE
  l_ids     id_table := new id_table( id_type( 1 ) );
  l_return  <<data type>>;
BEGIN
  l_return := a( l_ids );
END;
```

Comment: No, I brought SELECT FROM DUAL just as an example. Really I have multiple numbers to put into collection. And I'm going to SELECT these numbers.

Comment: @Oleg - If those numbers are coming from a table, you'd use the `BULK COLLECT`.  If you want to hard-code a list of numbers, you'd use the manual initialization approach from my last code snippet.